# How to convert diagram to LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I am new to LaTeX, and currently, I am trying to drawing this image in LaTeX. Could someone help me on that? It's quite difficult for me.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be wonderful if you could post some code that you've tried, even if it doesn't work. This will help us to see where you're stuck and provide the best help to you.

Comment: We don't usually like “do it for me” questions. We prefer to help you with something in particular. For instance you can use TikZ to draw that.

Comment: do you need to draw this in latex? (You have the option of simply including the image)

Comment: this is mighty similar to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163481/specific-box-diagram-with-multiple-arrows).  Is there a generic place for "box-with-arrows" diagrams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
mynode/.style={
  draw,
  text width=2.2cm,
  align=center
  },
>=latex
]

% the nodes
\node[mynode]
  (soc) 
  {Species ocurrence data};
\node[mynode,text width=1.4cm,ellipse,above right=of soc]
  (theory) {Theory};
\node[
  mynode,
  double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex,shadow yshift=1ex},
  fill=white,
  right=4cm of soc
  ] 
  (ed) {Envionmental data};
\node[mynode,below right=of soc]
  (mf) {Modelling framework};
\node[mynode,below=of mf]
  (mpo) {Map of predicted occurrence};
% the arrows
\draw[->]
  (theory) to[out=180,in=90] 
    node[left=3pt] {Sample design} 
  (soc);
\draw[->]
  (soc) to[out=-90,in=180] 
    node[pos=0.3,right=3pt] {calibration} 
  ([yshift=5pt]mf.west);
\draw[->,dashed]
  ([yshift=-5pt]mf.west) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=1.3] 
    node[left=3pt] {validation} 
  (soc);
\draw[->]
  (theory) to[out=0,in=90] 
    node[pos=0.1,right=35pt] {Candidate variables} 
    node[pos=0.8,right=3pt] {Scale} 
  ([yshift=2ex]ed.north);
\draw[->]
  (ed) to[out=-90,in=0] 
  (mf);
\draw[->]
  (ed) to[out=-90,in=0] 
  (mpo);
\draw[->]
  (mf) --
  (mpo);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]